# ColdFusion: How can I write '<' or '>' to a CF file?

Tags: coldfusion, special-characters

The `>` and `<` are giving me problems when writing to a file. I know this should be a very simple thing but I'm clearly missing something.

I've tried assigning both chars to a variables and printing the variables as well as just printing in quotes but nothing has worked.

I'm trying to print something along the lines of... `<some tag>blah, blah, blah</some tag>`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm unable to edit your post, due to the length restrictions, but you should add the ` character around the tags in your question, so that they appear in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for fixing, Leigh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
<cfset str = "Example < text >">
<cffile action="write" addnewline="yes" file="#ExpandPath('test.txt')#"  output="#str#" fixnewline="yes">
```

Comment: Hmm... saving the entire string to a variable fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem writing < or > to a file just as-is: they are not special characters as far as CF is concerned.  So I reckon you're going about things the wrong way.  But it's difficult to tell what you're doing without seeing some code...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to use [character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_html_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML):

- `&gt;` instead of `>`
- `&lt;` instead of `<`